# Disable music in CoD: Black Ops 3

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

Since the update the other night there seems to be music at the start and throughout multiplayer. How can I disable it?

Platform: PS4

Comment: You mentioned the latest Call of Duty. I've edited your question to reflect the specific game.

Comment: I tagged it PS4. @DangerZone removed it.

Comment: @user5603796 - You can specify the system in the body, but for the most part those tags are for referencing specific issues with the system itself, not playing a game on that console. I will add PS4 into the body for you. (if you hover over the tags, you can see the specific usage, usually)

Comment: Ah ok, I'm used to SO where we just add all tags that are relevant. Sorry, learnt now ;-)

Comment: @user5603796 Yeah, Arqade hates tags. If you have more than one they almost always get removed by somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable the music by navigating to:

**Options** > **Audio** > **Multiplayer Music** > **Disable**

It works for me, and I used this "source" [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/blackops3/comments/3s1a33/can_you_disable_the_intro_music_in_multiplayer/) to double check.